Check if the powerset of a group under a given binary operation is a group itself?
G is a group and $\mathcal{P}(G)$ the power set of G.
Let $(\mathbb{A},\mathbb{B})\rightarrow  \mathbb{A}\cdot \mathbb{B}=\{{ab\in G: a\in \mathbb{A}, b\in \mathbb{B}}\}$.
I have already shown that this map is associative. Now I'm asked to determine the neutral element. Since G is a group I can choose the singleton {e} with the neutral element of G. That's my neutral element.
Now since $\emptyset\subset\mathcal{P}(G)$ we would need an inverse for $\emptyset$ to make this a group. But since $(\mathbb{A},\emptyset)\rightarrow\emptyset$ for every $\mathbb{A}\subset \mathcal{P}(G)$ it doesn't exist and therefore this isn't a group.
Is this right?
I would appreciate only hints because I want to get better.

It makes no sense to say “check if the power set of a group is a group.” A power set is a set. A group is a set and a binary operation, which satisfies certain axioms. What you really want to say is “check if the power set of a group with this very specific binary operation is a group.”

Thank you! I have changed the title

Looks fine to me.

In fact, the only invertible elements of $\mathcal P(G)$ are the singletons. To prove this, we first note that $\varnothing$ is not invertible, as you have pointed out in the question. On the other hand, suppose $AB={e}$ where $A$ and $B$ are nonempty subsets of $G$. Choose an $a\in A$. Then, for all $b\in B$ we must have $ab=e$. But since the inverse of $a\in G$ is unique, this means that $B$ can only have one element. Similarly, $A$ can only have one element. We conclude that $A={a}$ and $B={a^{-1}}$.

(I deleted my answer because I agree that your question is a duplicate. But I've posted the second paragraph as a comment above.)
